# Implementing a since-last-activity timeout with OAuth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

We are:

- Using OAuth for both authorization and authentication
- Using the implicit-grant flow (i.e. client-side flow)
- Issuing relatively short-lived access tokens (measured in hours, not weeks)

I want to offer a comparable experience to the traditional expiring-cookie policy, where you get a certain amount of time that your credentials will work, but if you stay active on the site that window continually resets. I'm realizing that this is not straightforward in OAuth. Yes, tokens are issued with an expiry time, but most implementations keep that time fixed regardless of activity.

This isn't so weird when issuing extremely long-lived tokens as one does when authorizing an integration (like, say, a Twitter app). But it's weird when using OAuth for user-facing authentication. If we issue a short-lived token and the user goes for a big session on our site, their access may run out abruptly even though they are in the middle of something. Even if we issued a token valid for 24 hours, if the user comes back 23.75 hours later, they're going to get 15 good minutes and then suddenly get kicked off.

I'm trying to figure out how to offer my users a better experience while sticking to OAuth mechanics. So far, my best idea is to change the server-side implementation to update the expiry date on the token on each authenticated request (this only works because our tokens have a server-side component - I don't know how it could work if we went the self-contained token route). And then, to keep the client appraised of the updated expiry time, we'll want to send that back with our response, maybe in a header, or a `meta` attribute in the JSON object.

This approach seems a little complicated, but workable. Is there a better way? Has anyone else dealt with this issue? Am I nuts for even trying?

Comment: you really can't use OAuth 2.0 for authentication, only partly for reasons that you describe; see here for a more exhaustive writeup: http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/

Comment: @HansZandbelt Thanks for the link. I think [this draft](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) is where I would be looking if I were implementing OpenID. However, it still doesn't mention my use case explicitly -- it only talks about handling logout events. So I'm still not clear on how the OP would decide when to bump the expiry, and how it would communicate that to the RP.

Comment: the OpenID Connect session management spec is not only about logout but also about sharing session changes between OP and RPs via iframes; other than that, the RP can use the Refresh Token Request to renew the id_token it got earlier and its associated expiry